# Installed OS on EFI system crashes on grub shell

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, fedora, grub

I have installed an el6 based custom OS on an e-mmc drive. This machine doesn't have legacy boot mode, only EFI. The installed OS has `grub-0.97-77.el6.x86_64.rpm`.

Using a rescue disk I can see that the OS is installed on the mmc drive, but I am unable to boot the installed system. grub crashes to a minimal shell. Here are some info.

```
~]# /boot/grub/device.map
 (hd0)   /dev/mmcblk0
```

`mount` shows the following :

```
~]# mount      
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root on / type ext4 (rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/mmcblk0p2 on /boot type ext4 (rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=winnt,errors=remount-ro)
```

If I execute commands from a grub shell, it throws "No such partition" for `(hd0,1)`, which is the `/boot` or `/dev/mmcblk0p2` partition.

```
 grub> root (hd0,0)
 root (hd0,0)
 Filesystem type is fat, partition type 0x83

 grub> root (hd0,1)
 root (hd0,1)
 Error 22?: No such partition
```

This is the output of `parted` command on `/dev/mmcblk0`:

```
~]# parted /dev/mmcblk0
 GNU Parted 2.1
 Using /dev/mmcblk0
 Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
 (parted) print                                                            
 Model: MMC BGND3R (sd/mmc)
 Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 31.3GB
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
 Partition Table: gpt

 Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  211MB   210MB   fat16              boot
 2      211MB   1285MB  1074MB  ext4
 3      1285MB  31.3GB  30.0GB                     lvm
```

**Note** I could install and boot Fedora-22/23 without any problem on the same machine.

Answer (score 2):

That package version suggests you're using Grub Legacy (0.97), which according to this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Boot_loaders, does not support UEFI.  Please see that article for other boot loaders you can use.

Also, to avoid any confusion please be aware that Arch calls Grub 2 "Grub" and Grub .97 "Grub Legacy".

Comment: Thanks for the hint... I will give EFIStub booting a try. Do you think it should work in the same way for a RHEL/CentOS based linux ?

Comment: I haven't tried EFIStub, but I've used Grub 2 with success for UEFI compatible machines.  Currently I use no bootloader at all on my EFI machine and just boot directly into Linux, but this requires a more customized setup.

Comment: What is the customized setup. Would like to share in your answer ? I have no luck using EFI_STUB.

Comment: What issue are you having with EFIStub?  Maybe I can help.

Comment: My solution is to recompile the kernel, setting all of my kernel parameters directly in the kernel config instead of receiving them from the bootloader (root=PARTUID=..., etc.).  Next step is to drop the vmlinuz into /boot/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi.  This location is the default boot location any UEFI-compatible system.  Here are the drawbacks to this setup:
1) this solution doesn't accomodate an initrd.
2) this solution doesn't allow me to pass any additional parameters to the kernel (they're all hardcoded).  As there is no bootloader handoff I would have to recompile the kernel to change them.

Comment: Make BOOTX64 a UEFI shell.  From the shell prompt, you can then invoke your Linux kernel with command line arguments and an initrd.